# Any Performance difference between indexing using Solr and indexing using Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene

Is there any performance benefit on indexing data directly using Lucene as compared to using Solr which uses lucene internally anyway. I don't wish to reinvent the wheel I just want to know if there is any performance benefit when indexing large amount of documents directly using Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the performance...

Solr internally uses Lucene. Solr supports everything that is been supported by Lucene. Its sort of wrapper build on top of Lucene which provides other features. Other features include HTTP api, cloud/sharding/ replication supprot, web interface for analysing etc..

For other function, Solr totally depends on Lucene such as sorting , searching etc are the core of lucene..

Solr is build on top of Lucene to provide more feature ... it does not have any performance difference while indexing ...